# Display multiple nested li in three columns

Tags: css, list, unordered

I have below unordered list structure.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>Apple</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>Gala Apple</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>Berry</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Strawberry</a></li>
      <li><a>Rasperry</a></li>
      <li><a>Cranberry</a></li>
      <li><a>Blueberry</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>Pear</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>European Pear</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>Asian Pear</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>Melons</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>Water Melon</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>Winter Melon</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want the output to be in three rows with Apple,Berry items on first column, Pears on second, Melons on third column like below. Also if there is new addition for example if i add blue berry to the list, display should remain intact as below without moving to second column.

Desired output:

```
Apple           Pears              Melons
   Gala Apple     European Pear       Water Melon
Berry             Asian Pear          Winter Melon
   Strawberry
   Rasperry
   Cranberry 
   Blueberry
```

I tried below css but it shifts part of berry results to next column.

```
-webkit-column-count: 3;
-moz-column-count: 3;
column-count: 3;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed up the HTML a bit but this seems to work.

```css
.col{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<ul class='col'>
  <ul>
    <li>Apple</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Gala Apple</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li>Berry</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Strawberry</li>
      <li>Rasperry</li>
      <li>Cranberry</li>
      <li>Blueberry</li>           
    </ul>
  </ul>
</ul>

<ul class='col'>
<li>Pear</li>
  <ul>
    <li>European Pear</li>
    <li>Asian Pear</li>           
  </ul>
</ul>

<ul class='col'>
  <li>Melons</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Water Melon</li>
    <li>Winter Melon</li>           
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Kyle your answer works but issue is adding additional ul element which i may have to think. I will mark as answer if i dont get any idea.

Comment: For the first two <ul> to be displayed on top of each other I think the additional elements are needed as wrappers/parents. With everything being treated as one big list with a bunch of sub-lists it makes it difficult to separate them out in the format you want.

Answer (score 1):

Pradeep, how's this?

```css
.one {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: lightgray;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-grid;
}
.two {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-grid;
}
.three {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-grid;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <ul>
    <li> Apple </li>
    <ul>
      <li> Gala Apple </li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li> Berry </li>
    <ul>
      <li> Strawberry </li>
      <li> Rasperry </li>
      <li> Cranberry </li>
      <li> Blueberry </li> 
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="two">
  <ul>
    <li> Pear </li>
    <ul>
      <li> European Pear </li>
      <li> Asian Pear </li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="three">
  <ul>
    <li> Melons </li>
    <ul>
      <li> Water Melon </li>
      <li> Winter Melon </li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Ricky, If you see my question I want first two ul data to be in one column but your code display each ul in one column.

Comment: Let me fix that up for you. Give me a few mins.

Comment: Pradeep, what about now? I have edited my code snippet.