# How to display multilevel list in two columns without breaking the sublists?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, multiple-columns, laravel-blade

I have a multi-level HTML list like this generated from a blade template:

```
<ul style="columns: 2;">
    <li>Category 1</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Skill 1.1</li>
        <li>Skill 1.2</li>
        <li>Skill 1.3</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Category 2</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Skill 2.1</li>
        <li>Skill 2.2</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Category 3</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Skill 3.1</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Category 4</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Skill 4.1</li>
        <li>Skill 4.2</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

I want the output to be in two columns without breaking one of the sublists.
Here is the desired output:

```
Category 1       Category 3
    Skill 1.1        Skill 3.1
    Skill 1.2    Category 4
    Skill 1.3        Skill 4.1
Category 2           Skill 4.2
    Skill 2.1
    Skill 2.2
```

My problem is that "Skill 2.2" is in the second column because the system makes two columns trying to have the same numbers of rows as much as possible.

I already saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44592562/display-multiple-nested-li-in-three-columns) but all the answers advice to update the HTML.
I would prefer to only use CSS because I get my items from the database and the number of nodes can change. I also want to avoid as much as possible to add logic in my blade template like counters to start the second column, instead there's no other solution.

I made a [codepen](https://codepen.io/pierre-adrien-maison/pen/JjGGXWV) to illustrate the problem.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ul ul { page-break-inside: avoid; }`. This will avoid page breaks within sub-lists (i.e. any `ul` inside a `ul`), and regarding this, column-breaks act like page-breaks:

```css
ul ul  {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

```html
<ul style="columns: 2;">
  <li>Category 1</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Skill 1.1</li>
    <li>Skill 1.2</li>
    <li>Skill 1.3</li>
  </ul>
  <li>Category 2</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Skill 2.1</li>
    <li>Skill 2.2</li>
  </ul>
  <li>Category 3</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Skill 3.1</li>
  </ul>
  <li>Category 4</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Skill 4.1</li>
    <li>Skill 4.2</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Addition after comment:

Actually sub-lists are usually nested in a different way: The second-level-`ul` is *inside*  a first-level-`li`. If you change the HTML this way, you can use `ul > li { page-break-inside: avoid; }`, which will also take care of the problem you mention, as demonstrated in this second snippet:

```css
ul > li {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

```html
<ul style="columns: 2;">
  <li>Category 1
    <ul>
      <li>Skill 1.1</li>
      <li>Skill 1.2</li>
      <li>Skill 1.3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Category 2
    <ul>
      <li>Skill 2.1</li>
      <li>Skill 2.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Category 3
    <ul>
      <li>Skill 3.1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, it actually works in this case but if you remove "Category 4" and its children, "Category 2" stay on the left column but its children are on the right one. Any idea to keep all the parent + children together ?

Comment: please note the addition to my initial answer